# Computing the limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I usually use L'Hopital's rule to compute a limit, but in these two cases, I don't know how to break it down.

a) $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}(2^n+3^n)^{1/n}$

b) $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\{(2+\sqrt{3})^n\}$, where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$

Comment: This question makes no sense as written.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE: It is fixed now.

Comment: Common misconception: L'Hospital's rule will solve everything.

Comment: The Maple command $$Student[Calculus1]:-LimitTutor((3^n+2^n)^(1/n), n = infinity) $$ does the job, outputing $3$ with explanations. See [that link](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) for info.

Comment: @Cameron Buie, thank you for editing my post, I got really hard time with Tex typing.

Comment: It takes getting used to, but you'll pick it up with practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For the first, use **Squeezing**. We have 
$$3\lt (2^n+3^n)^{1/n}\lt 2^{1/n}(3).$$

For the second, note that $(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n$ is always an integer. But $(2-\sqrt{3})^n$ approaches $0$ from above, so our limit is $1$.

Comment: For the second, you must also remark that $2-\sqrt 3>0$ i.e. the convergence to $0$ is from above. For example $\{(2+\sqrt 5)^n\}$ does *not* converge because it oscillates between $\approx 0$ and $\approx 1$.

Comment: True. I had left things to do.

Answer (score 1):

Another (slower) approach:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}(2^n+3^n)^\frac{1}{n}=2\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(1+\bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^n \bigg)^\frac{1}{n}=2 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log (1+(\frac{3}{2}))^n}{n}=2 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(\frac{3}{2})^n \log \frac{3}{2}}{1+(\frac{3}{2})^n}=2\cdot \frac{3}{2}=3
$$
The third step is taking logarithm, then applying L'Hospital's rule and taking the limit and then exponentiating.